# Use original template under admin directory

Tags: python, django

I have django script with administration page `/admin`

Now I want to make another page `/customdata` for administration purpose.

However in this page , `customdata` is not related to specific model, it just shows the system overview data.

It is just the normal template.

Now I have two ideas.

1. Making independent `www.myexample.com/customdata` page and set authentication.
2. Linking this under `www.myexample.com/admin/customdata` and treat it as admin page

2 sounds usefule to me, because pages for administration purpose should be togetter.

However is it possible? or is it not good behaivor?

Comment: It's possible! I've got one for my currently logged in users. This seems to be the non-idiotic way [Stackoverflow Custom Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053981/how-can-i-create-custom-page-for-django-admin) you'll just have to add a manual check for if it's an admin or not ..My solution was to override the entire AdminSite object and make a new function for the view- which a little over the top in hindsight

Comment: Didi you mean that you want the `\customdata` point to current admin page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create custom page for django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053981/how-can-i-create-custom-page-for-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend base Django admin for more info check this out blog.

https://dev.to/daiquiri_team/creating-a-custom-page-in-django-admin-4pbd